How can we construct reals from Cauchy sequences if the definition of Cauchy makes uses reals?
My understanding the definition of a Cauchy sequence is that it is a sequence $a_n$. Which has the property.
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n,m \geq N | a_n - a_m |< \epsilon$$
However all the definitions on line I've found say that $\epsilon$ is a real number.  But if you are constructing the reals then you don't have access to reals yet.  It feels like a circular definition.
I know you can construct the reals from Dedekind cuts so you could use that to bootstrap Cauchy sequences that way... but then you also have a perfectly good construction of the reals.

It might be a good exercise to convince yourself that this definition of Cauchy sequence is equivalent to that where you restrict yourself to rational $\epsilon$'s :)

In the definition of a Cauchy sequence, you could require that $\epsilon$ is rational. This would give you a completely equivalent definition without any reals.

You can define with requiring $\epsilon$ to be rational. But I personally prefer the definition using Dedekind cuts. After we already have the reals, I do like the construction of completion of metric spaces with Cauchy sequences though.
